# Configuration Bundle on eZpublish 5x

Tags: symfony, bundle, ezpublish

I'm new on eZpublish 5x.
I would like change the default pagelayout demo.
It's possible to know how to change de default pagelayout demo and use my new bundle please.
I Have my new bundle, registered properly in kernel.

Thanks Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple way to achieve what you want, and it really depends on you actually. I suggest that you have a look at these ones:

-
 https://doc.ezplatform.com/en/1.7/tutorials/platform_beginner/3_customizing_the_general_layout/
 - https://symfony.fi/ez-platform-tip/setting-default-pagelayout-for-content-in-ez-platform

Pretty sure that you'll find what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but i don't use ezplatform but i use eZ Publish Community Project 2014.11

Comment: This should work as well for 2014.11. The configuration file might have changed a bit between the 2 versions but I'm sure you'll find what you want easily.